# Allocate CUDA pinned memory in a Fortran program with C wrapper (WITHOUT PGI CUDA Fortran)

Tags: cuda, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am trying to let a Fortran program (main) write/read pinned memory allocated by CUDA C/C++, but tests show even `cudaHostAlloc` from a C wrapper would return error.

Fortran accessing CUDA C/C++ `malloc` memory can be done following ["Passing allocatable array from fortran to C and malloc it"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147743/passing-allocatable-array-from-fortran-to-c-and-malloc-it), however, simply substituting `malloc` with `cudaMallocHost` or `cudaHostAlloc` will return `cudaErrorMemoryAllocation` (can successfully compile).

ifort is used for Fortran. Below is the not working code:
***edited to include the whole script**

```
//CUDA C/C++ host function in "cudaMallocHost.cu"
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cstdio>

extern "C" {
int *alloc_test(size_t size) {
    int *a;
    size_t fm, gm;
    cudaMemGetInfo(&fm, &gm);
    printf("GPU memory usage: %lu/%lu MB\n", fm / 1024 / 1024,
            gm / 1024 / 1024);
    cudaHostAlloc((void **) &(a), sizeof(int) * size, cudaHostAllocDefault);
    printf("%s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));
    //       a=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);  // 'malloc' works
    return a;
}
void destroy_test(int *ptr) {
    cudaFreeHost(ptr);
    printf("%s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));
    //       free(ptr);
}
}
```

```
! FORTRAN program in "main.f"
    PROGRAM fortran_side
      USE ISO_C_BINDING
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTERFACE
        FUNCTION alloc_test(s) BIND(C, NAME='alloc_test')
          USE ISO_C_BINDING
          IMPLICIT NONE
          TYPE(C_PTR)   :: alloc_test
          INTEGER(C_SIZE_T) :: s
        END FUNCTION alloc_test
        SUBROUTINE destroy_test(p) BIND(C, NAME='destroy_test')
          USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_PTR
          IMPLICIT NONE
          TYPE(C_PTR), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: p
        END SUBROUTINE destroy_test
      END INTERFACE

      TYPE(C_PTR) :: p
      INTEGER(C_INT), POINTER :: array(:)
      INTEGER(C_SIZE_T)       :: sz
      INTEGER(4)              :: i

      sz=4
      p = alloc_test(sz)
      CALL C_F_POINTER(p, array, [sz])

      DO i=1,sz
        array(i)=i*3
      END DO

      PRINT*,array

      CALL destroy_test(p)
    END PROGRAM fortran_side
```

```
#Makefile
all: cudaMallocHost.o main.f
    ifort -L/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib -lcudart -lcufft -O0 -132 \
        cudaMallocHost.o main.f -o ./test

clean:
    rm  -f *.o *.mod ./test
%.o: %.cu
    nvcc -arch sm_30 -O0 -c $*.cu -o $*.o
```

Output:

```
GPU memory usage: 836/2047 MB
out of memory
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
```

Is `cudaMallocHost` doable in a Fortran main program? I have tried PGI CUDA Fortran and it can have this done quite easily, without involving Fortran/C mixed programing. I have also tried pure CUDA `cudaMallocHost` and it also works on my system (Mac).

Comment: Exactly *how* is the code not working? Doesn't compile, doesn't link, segfaults at runtime? You are using C bindings in Fortran, but CUDA is a variant of C++, so uses name decoration for functions. So I am guessing you are getting a link-time error. If so, use `export "C"` on the CUDA side to force a C-style (rather than C++-style) interface. Please post enough code that someone else can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @njuffa Script and description updated. The Fortran & Cuda C/C++ `malloc` array exchange works by simply following common Fortran & C/C++ interoperation examples. But when it involves Cuda pinned memory, there will be runtime segfaults. Thanks

Comment: @TianyuLiu: Can you be a bit more specific? When during execution does the segfault occur? What compilers and CUDA version are you using? You have no CUDA runtime API error checking anywhere, are you certain that no CUDA errors are occurring at runtime? I can see several potential problems with what you are doing, but I don't know whether they are important or not without a well defined problem, which you have not yet provided.

Comment: @talonmies: You are right, the error happens on `cudaMallocHost`, which doesn't happen on a pure CUDA test. The whole test script is corrected & posted and question title updated. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C function

```
int *alloc_test(size_t size)
```

expects its argument by value, but your Fortran interface passes it by reference

```
    FUNCTION alloc_test(s) BIND(C, NAME='alloc_test')
      ...
      INTEGER(C_SIZE_T) :: s
```

to pass it by value use

```
      INTEGER(C_SIZE_T), VALUE :: s
```

Comment: Exactly. This causes an out-of-memory error because of the nonsensical size provided to the cuda API within the C code. The C returns an uninitialised pointer which then segfaults in the calling Fortan